# C++ Templates: Do they create a new object and destoy them at the end of the function / method?

Tags: c++, object, templates

I am trying to write a generic template method that renders a simple Rectangle to the screen using an object with the needed members. However, i noticed that the destuctors keeps being called. Now for this, it is not so much a problem, but for other templates I have in mind, it would (textures for example).

So does a template always create a copy of the object passed as an argument?

```
template<typename T>
    void renderRect(T thisObject, int red, int green, int blue, int alpha)
    {
        SDL_Rect object = { thisObject.x, thisObject.y, thisObject.w, thisObject.h };

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(this->renderer, red, green, blue, alpha);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(this->renderer, &object);
    }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with templates. `thisObject` is passed by value, hence copied.

Comment: Lol, I am new to cpp. But I understand, thats so basic (dumb) :) Thx for the quick response :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `T` is an object type (e.g. a `class` or a `struct`), then indeed `T thisObject` does take a value copy.

Did you want `void renderRect(const T& thisObject, int red, int green, int blue, int alpha)`?

Comment: Yes, this was my first attempt at templates, never even crossed my mind that I needed to pass it by reference (Am I saying that correctly?). But its so obvious now. Much appreciated :)

Comment: @Lyingdutchman Oh it's a murky world: whole books are dedicated to the subject. A personal favourite: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Templates-Complete-Guide-David-Vandevoorde/dp/0321714121 (Main author is a fellow Dutchman!).

Comment: Much appreciated, will definitely look into that!